# Spring boot performance

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, kubernetes, tomcat

I have some spring boot app performance problem.

I am using spring boot 3.0.0, Java 17, embeded tomcat. Application connects to DB and redis. Deployment is done on k8s.
When application is deployed(or restarted) and traffic is enabled to instances then in the first 5 minutes application is very slow. P99 is 2s and slowly goes down to 100ms. After 5 minutes everything looks great.

The problem only exits if pods in k8s are newly created.

The problem does not exist if an app was warmed up with initial requests.

I tried lots of stuff and configuration changes from database pool connection to tomcat thread pool but nothing seems to work.

The only thing that works is that app needs to be warmed up with production load. On production we have 2k rps. When app is warmed up with let's say 500 rps for few minutes then once the production traffic is enabled the problem comes back(but it is a bit better though)

Do you have any idea how to handle that ? I am getting out of ideas actually

Comment: You can use a profiler like Java Flight Recorder to monitor your application and discover the bottlenecks in your app.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case, we resolved our issue by 'creating' some threads manually before we mark the app as ready (in k8s we used the liveness probe). Now i guess there are different ways to do that. Some thread pools have a property for minimum ready threads or you can use a for loop to create N threads in a custom way.

Unfortunately, k8s doesnt have a config to slowly introduce a new pod with less requests for the first X seconds so you need to go for an ugly custom solution.

From design perspective, you can redeploy pods during low traffic times (which still leaves some risky cases of random redeploys from k8s or restarts etc).
You could also use more pods maybe, by reducing the load a pod can handle and scale vertically. This way you will never have a case of a pod starting with X/5 but get maximum X/10 which might do the trick